# "Is about right" (meaning)

Tags: sentence-meaning

(Excerpt)

> Do you think that the balance between work and free time in your country **is about right?**

What does **''is about right''** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"About right" is a phrase meaning "approximately correct" or "roughly accurate".

English also uses the phrase "just right" to mean exactly correct. As an aside, there is an English fable about Goldilocks and the three bears that relates to this idea so you sometimes hear "Goldilocks" referenced when talking about something being just right.

Comment: I like a particular sentence in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_and_the_Three_Bears#Literary_elements) on the English fable you cite: _Author Christopher Booker characterises this as the "dialectical three", where "the first is wrong in one way, the second in another or opposite way, and only the third, in the middle, is just right."_ It explains how "just right" refers to being at an ideal place along a spectrum. For example, a driver can drive too fast, or too slow, or "just right" – meaning, "at a speed that is neither too slow or too fast."